# Trying to start Symfony Routing component

Tags: php, symfony, components

I'm trying to use Symfony Routing component but I can't understand one thing - how should I set path to controller in my instance of `Route` class?

For example, I have a `/web` directory where I placed my `app.php` file with code:

```
$route = new Route('/{name}', array('controller' => 'IndexController.php'));
```

and in same directory placed also `IndexController.php` file where placed function which should accept parameter name and return some value:

```
class IndexController
{

    public function helloAction($name) {
        return 'Hello '. $name;
    }

}
```

But when I go to some path, for ex `/test` I see just blank page.

How I should set path to Controller and Action function?

Comment: Just to clarify, is creating the Route object all you are doing? Because you need a routing infrastructure to actually route.  Are you following: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#usage

Comment: No, it's just a one line of code:)

Comment: Okay.  Start by following the link I gave you.  That will give you the parameters for the matched route.  After that you will need to implements some sort of controller resolver to actually execute the controller method.  Lots of fun.  This might be helpful: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set path to your Controller - you should follow [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and put FQCN under 'controller' key (or just `IndexController::class`)

Answer (score 0):

Your `IndexController` should not be in the `/web` folder, but in the`/src/YourBundleName` folder and you need to register your route in the Symfony first.

Use Symfony console to generate a bundle and a controller for you:

```
// Generate bundle
php bin/console generate:bundle

// Generate controller
php bin/console generate:controller
```

The controller generator asks you for routes and it generate routes for you automatically.

Use can use another Symfony console command to check your registered routes:

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

If you can't see your route here, it's not registered and you can't access it.

Comment: I'm not use Symfony, I'm just trying to implement separate components of Symfony in my project